# knockout.js api search form

Tags: api, knockout.js

The goal of my code is to search on the API search string:

So if you fill out the form you get the hits bij name.

I used the following Knockout.js script:

```
var viewModel=
{
    query : ko.observable("wis"),
};

function EmployeesViewModel(query)
{
    var self = this;
    self.employees = ko.observableArray();
    self.query = ko.observable(query);
    self.baseUri = BASE + "/api/v1/search?resource=employees&field=achternaam&q=";

    self.apiurl = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.baseUri + self.query();
    }, self);
    //$.getJSON(baseUri, self.employees);
    //$.getJSON(self.baseUri, self.employees);
    $.getJSON(self.apiurl(), self.employees);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new EmployeesViewModel(viewModel.query()));
});
```

The html binding is:

```
<input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" id="global-search" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>
```

But if i fill  the text box i onley get the default "wis" employees? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your html with binding too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found a solution.

```
var employeesModel = function(){

        var self = this;

        self.u = base +'/api/v1/search';
        self.resource = 'employees';
        self.field = 'achternaam';
        self.employees = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.q = ko.observable();

        //Load Json when model is setup
        self.dummyCompute = ko.computed(function() {
            $.getJSON(self.u,{'resource': self.resource, 'field': self.field, 'q':self.q }, function(data) {
                    self.employees(data);
             });

        }, self);
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new employeesModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what is wrong here, but have you debugged it and seen what the value of query is in apiurl?

One potential issue is that you are passing employees to `getJSON` as the observable, not the underlying array, so you could try:

```
$.getJSON(self.apiurl(), self.employees());
```

Comment: $.getJSON(self.apiurl(), self.employees()); was one of the things I tried but it seems query value isn't passed. it returns undifined

Comment: Not sure what that comment is meant to mean!

Comment: $.getJSON(self.apiurl(), self.employees()); was one of the things I tried but it seems the query value isn't passed correct. It returns "undefined".

Comment: With some debuging i found " Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option." for the self.apiurl  value.

Comment: Where are you actually trying to write to a computed?

Comment: it refrences to: self.apiurl = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.baseUri + self.query();
    }, self);

Comment: the computed has to return: BASE + "/api/v1/search?resource=employees&field=achternaam&q=" + input from the form field.